# Cut an email if the string size is upper than a value

Tags: macros, longtable

I've a really long document that I generat with a python script. A big part of the doc uses `longtable` with an email adress:

```
\begin{longtable}{p{0.3\linewidth}p{0.3\linewidth}p{0.3\linewidth}}
 value & john@doe.com & text \\
\end{longtable}
```

It happens that the email adress is really long and in this case I want to "cut" the email after the @:

```
\begin{longtable}{p{0.3\linewidth}p{0.3\linewidth}p{0.3\linewidth}}
 value & johnveryveryverylongname@\newline doe.com & text \\
\end{longtable}
```

How can I test the string length and put the `\newline` after the `@`?

Comment: I would not do that at all but just use url package `\url{johnveryveryverylongname@doe.com}` and it will (or can be specified to) break at @ or . or any other characters you need then the ususal tex line breaking algorithm will do the measuring

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible with `collcell`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{collcell}

\newcommand{\cutlongemail}[1]{%
  \sbox0{#1}%
  \ifdim\wd0 > \linewidth
    \docutlongemail#1\relax
  \else
    #1%
  \fi
}
\def\docutlongemail#1@#2\relax{#1@\newline#2}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{
  p{0.3\linewidth}
  >{\collectcell\cutlongemail}p{0.3\linewidth}<{\endcollectcell}
  p{0.3\linewidth}
}
value & john@doe.com & text \\
value & johnveryverylongname@doe.com & text \\
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @RomainPicot It will make an overfull box if the first part of the address is *very* long.

Comment: I know but modifying 30 000 lines manually or less than ten it's "different" ;-)